# HBase Shell query based on RowKey postfix

Tags: hbase

If I have the following row keys in HBase:

```
abc_DFS_20
sjd_eir_21
skd_err_22
...
..
sdf_rie_100
```

For now I want to use HBase Shell to query all the rowkeys which *_ * _number from 30 - 40, so something like

```
scan 'table', {STARTROW => '*_*_30', ENDROW => '*_*_40'}
```

Acutally the above query doesn't work. Could anyone give me an idea to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Talked about it multiple times here, wildcards are not supported, only prefixes can be used as start & stop rows. You have a few options, each one with its own pros & cons (sorted by less complexity/overhead):

1. Store the value on a column and perform a table scan (no prefix) with a **SingleColumnValue** filter (server-side full table scan required).
2. **[FuzzyRowFilter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FuzzyRowFilter.html) + SingleColumnValue** filter or a **Custom filter** so rows that don't match with your pattern can be skipped (server-side full table scan required but it will fast forward faster).
3. **Automatic secondary-indexes** through a coprocessor (not natively supported).
4. **Manually maintain or dual/write to a secondary-index** table (realtime fast) in which the rowkey is your prefix (ie: 20_DFS_abc, 21_sjd_eir ...)

You can find more info [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book/secondary.indexes.html).